# Can we do these haram things in Jannah?

Tags: nikah, jannah, homosexuality, halal-haram

I have been reading up on the relationships in Jannah, & i came across a forum of fellow Muslim brothers saying a few things. Id greatly appreciate a numbered response to each question please!(these questions come from Quran, the forum, & some things i heard Muslims say like Mohammed Hijab for example)

1.Is there such thing as haram in Jannah? (i was told there is no such thing as morality in Jannah)

2.Is it true that pedophilia will be allowed in Jannah if asked for because it is not pedophilia? (this is what they said on the forum)

3.Is it true homosexuality will be halal in Jannah if we abstain in this life? (they said in Quran it mentions beautiful boy servants & that nothing is immoral and it will be okay because in Jannah there wont be disease like AIDS)

4.It says in Quran we will get 2 wives, but what if i dont want two wives? I want to be with my wife only, i love her so much & even though jealousy wont exist i still dont want anyone but her.

5. Is it true if my wife and other women will have men servants & if they choose can have a better husband or more men in Jannah?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first clarify the situation in Jannah. Everything you like is allowed in Jannah, but you will not like anything there. That's the point. Here we may like things which might be either good or bad, but in Jannah people are purified before entering Jannah, so they will only like what is good. This opinion is backed with at least Shia Ahadeeth interpreting verses of Quran, mentioning Allah purifying Ahl-ul Jannah before their entrance to Jannah:

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ يَشْتَرُونَ بِعَهْدِ اللَّـهِ وَأَيْمَانِهِمْ ثَمَنًا
> قَلِيلًا أُولَـٰئِكَ لَا خَلَاقَ لَهُمْ فِي الْآخِرَةِ وَلَا
> يُكَلِّمُهُمُ اللَّـهُ وَلَا يَنظُرُ إِلَيْهِمْ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ
> وَ **لَا يُزَكِّيهِمْ** وَ لَهُمْ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ
>
> Indeed, those who exchange the covenant of Allah and their [own] oaths
> for a small price will have no share in the Hereafter, and Allah will
> not speak to them or look at them on the Day of Resurrection, **nor will**
> **He purify them**; and they will have a painful punishment.

In this verse, Allah states who He will not purify at the judgment day, and will punish instead. This is totally the reverse for those going to the hell, as they will ask Allah in hell for what will be bad for them, increasing their punishment.They are those who frequently used to request for what was indeed bad for them.

> قَدْ أَفْلَحَ مَن زَكَّاهَا ﴿٩﴾ وَقَدْ خَابَ مَن دَسَّاهَا ﴿١٠﴾
>
> He has succeeded who purifies it, (9) And he has failed who instills
> it [with corruption]. (10)

Now about your questions in order:

1. No
2. Seemingly not, as far as I can say, because it is against the intrinsic nature of humankind
3. The same as above
4. There will be no force over you to have two wives ...
5. According to a Shia Hadeeth, if you are higher ranked in Jannah, and your wife is also in Jannah, you can ask Allah to let her come to you, and if she is higher ranked that you and you are in Jannah as well, she can ask Allah to let you go to her. So yes, it is possible that she will not ask to be with you, so better to try harder and be a better servant of Allah :)